# spring boot mail cannot find JavaMailSender to autowire

Tags: spring-boot, email

Just trying to run the following test.

I am getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] when I run it.

What am i missing?

pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SendEmailTest {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailService;

@Test
public void testSendEmail() {

    SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
    String msgText = "This is your <b>mail message</b> from the <h3>Java Test</h3> !";

    mailMessage.setTo("xxx.yyy@zzzz.com");
    mailMessage.setSubject("A test from Java");
    mailMessage.setText(msgText);

    javaMailService.send(mailMessage);
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = YourApplication.class)
    public class SendEmailTest {

        @Autowired
        private JavaMailSender javaMailService;

    }
```

In your configuaration class,

```
   @Bean
   public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {

        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setProtocol("SMTP");
        javaMailSender.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        javaMailSender.setPort(25);

        return javaMailSender;
    }
```

Comment: It seems it was down to the lack of the configuration class.